# Windows 10 freezes reproducible

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I have my Setup since a good year now, everything run stable( prime95 stress test 24H).

- i5-750 @4GHz
- GA-H55M-UD2H
- ASUS GTX670 DirectCu2

But lately its occasionally freezes. The monitor just shows the latest image, the keyboard doesn't work, neither does the start/restart button.

I have to pull the plug to restart.

That always happens after ~10mins when im playing Dark Souls 3.

I didn't install any new software besides DS3 nor could I find any relevant information in the event log besides the unexpected shutdowns.

Comment: Gaming puts heavy load on the system... sounds like overheating, unless it happens at exactly the same point, then I would say bad install or old video drivers.

Comment: The thing is, i can only reproduce it in DS3. Other games like KF2, Black Desert and others are fine and my drivers are updated.

Comment: undo the dramatic OC and look if system is stable again

Comment: I tryed that. The result was an incredible stuttering in DS3. Anything else stayed the same.

Comment: have you turned down the settings in DS3, a game, that has known performance problems on the PC.

Comment: At the last test i set the graphics to low but the same problem occurred.